Problem 27. Integrate a conditional BITWISE right-shift function.
This problem has been haunting me since I've seen it on Facebook.

The function $f$ converts $1$s into $01$s when written in binary,  e.g.,
when $a = 0.101$_bin, $f(a) = 0.01001$_bin.
Compute the integral: $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

There are a few people who have said that the answer is $\frac{1}{5}$ but I'm not sure how they got there.
I have gotten as far as representing the function in decimal instead of binary.
If $$x = 2^a + 2^b + 2^c + \cdots + 2^n$$
Then $$f(x) = 2^{a-1} + 2^{b-2} + 2^{c-3} + \cdots + 2^{n-k}$$
There was one comment that stated that if the integral is equal to $Y$ (substitution of sorts) then $Y = \frac{Y}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{Y}{8}$. This matches up with the $\frac{1}{5}$ answer but I'm not sure how they got there.
I would love to see some working out from start to finish.
Any help with understanding this would be absolutely appreciated.
Problem 27

First guess: to break the integral into $\int_0^{0.1_2}f(x)\ dx + \int_{0.1_2}^1f(x)\ dx$?

Though I would wonder if $f$ is even defined for terminating binary fractions: what are the values of $f\left(0.0\overline 1_2\right)$ and $f\left(0.1_2\right)$?

Terminating binary fractions are countable and so a measure zero subset of the reals, so it doesn’t affect the integral.

Following peterwhy's hint:
Let $I=I_0 + I_1$ where $I = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$, $I_0 = \int_0^{1/2} f(x) \, dx$, and $I_1 = \int_{1/2}^1 f(x) \, dx$.
For $x \in [0, 0.5)$, the binary representation of $x$ begins with "$0.0$" and we also have $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} f(2x)$. So $$I_0 = \int_0^{0.5} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{0.5} f(2x) \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 f(u) \, du = \frac{1}{4} I.$$
FOr $x \in [0.5, 1)$, the binary representation of $x$ begins with "$0.1$" and we also have $f(x) = f(\frac{1}{2} + x - \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}f(x - \frac{1}{2})$. So
$$I_1 = \int_{1/2}^1 f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^1 f(x-\frac{1}{2})\, dx
= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1/2} f(u) \, du
= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{2} I_0
= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} I.$$
